# All readings are within one sigma. What does this mean?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

A basic question from a novice to statistical concepts. I am doing a small test wherein I measured a 100 observations of a same reading to check for the repeatability of the measurement data. On checking the values, all of my values lie within mean+1*sigma and mean-1*sigma.

What I could understand from the 68-95-99.7 rule is that the probability is 99.7 if my values are within 3 sigmas of the mean. Now given that all my values lie even within one sigma, is this good or bad? I am not quite sure how to interpret this

Comment: This is true if your distribution is normal. Your distribution is not and you should inspect your data with other methods. Example where your situation may happen: multimodal distribution. It leads to terribly large SD estimations and you can observe what you do.

Comment: How do you come to know the value of $\sigma$? Or do you instead mean that all the observations are within one sample standard deviation of the sample mean?

Comment: It means either $\sigma$ is not the correct value for the standard deviation of the measurements or some implicit assumption (such as independence of measurements) does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Plotting a histogram of your observations is usually a good first step in analyzing your data, and can give you a great deal of intuition of what you are dealing with. You can then easily sanity check your data to make sure it is distributed the way you expect it to be, see potential outliers, and get the intuition/interpretations that you are after.